# How to filter multiple columns with multiple criteria simultaneously in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want a VBA code to be created for which I have an excel range as shown below. I want to filter 2 columns simultaneously, ‘Assignment Group’ column should not be filtered with “ITO LUX AAT Wintel”, “SAP Basis NTT” and “(Blanks)” and for the ‘Date’ column if today is Monday this column should be filtered with dates greater than today’s date minus 4 (>date-4) if not then it should be filtered with dates greater than today’s date minus 2 (>date-2) and “(Blanks)”.

Can anyone help with this one? am trying to do this with autofilter, however, I tried the advance filter as well to do this but couldn't get the result, so if I can get the solution by using Auto or advance filter, works for me.

[image]

Comment: `‘Assignment Group’ column should not be filtered with “ITO LUX AAT Wintel”, “SAP Basis NTT” and “(Blanks)”` this is a little unclear.

Comment: I would add a helper column to flag the relevant records.  Without it, you're going to have to iterate through all the possible values in 'Assignment Group" and exclude the specified values.

Comment: OK so `‘Assignment Group’ column should not be filtered to NOT(“ITO LUX AAT Wintel”, “SAP Basis NTT”, “(Blanks)”)`

Comment: @FrankBall, I did not get your point, could you please elaborate a little.

Comment: @TimWilliams, ‘Assignment Group’ column should not be filtered with “ITO LUX AAT Wintel”, “SAP Basis NTT” and “(Blanks)” means that we need to filter the Assignment Group column with everything except these values

Comment: @TimWilliams yes, but how to write this in the code? could you please advise

Comment: Add a column to your data that will hold a formula that identifies the lines based on your criteria.  Just have it return True/False and use that column to filter your data.  The benefit of this is that VBA doesn't handle filtering data using "Not in a list of values" logic without iterating through all of the values and filtering out the irrelevant data.

Comment: Why don't you share the codes you have tried especially the one using `Advanced Filter`?